# Вывести только дату и время postgres

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в postgresql записать дату в таком формате

`"2020-05-25 15:57:31"`
 через now()?

Столбец у меня timestamp without time zone, вызываю функцию now(), но она записывает время в таком формате
`"2020-05-25 15:57:31.489"`.

Как из now() получить дату и время без ".489"?

Comment: Может есть функции округления для timestamp? Руководство postgres не смотрели?

Comment: @Sergey смотрели, но не нашли. Существуют константы для округления даты (типа microseconds,second и тд), то есть перечень их удалось найти, а пример применения этих констант к функции now() у меня не получилось найти.

Comment: `SELECT date_trunc('second', now()::timestamp);`

Answer (score 4):

Собственно если вам не нужны доли секунд - то это можно указать в типе данных дополнительным [параметром `p`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html): `timestamp(0) without time zone`, который как раз и означает число знаков в долях секунды.

```
melkij=> create temp table foo (dt timestamp(0) without time zone);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into foo values(now());
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> table foo;
         dt          
---------------------
 2020-05-25 16:33:05
```

---

Для отбрасывания части `timestamp` от уже имеющегося значения подходит штатная функция `date_trunc`

```
 SELECT date_trunc('second', timestamp_value)
```